# How can I create file in my source directory project via custom gradle plugin?

Tags: gradle

I have next the default structure project:

```
src -> main -> java -> my package
```

And custom gradle plugin:

```
class CustomPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.task('createFile') << {
            //Creating file in source directory
        }
    }
}
```

I want create file in my `src` directory when I call custom task via my gradle plugin. How to do it? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: CustomPlugin

class CustomPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.task('createFile') << {
            new File(project.file('src'), 'some-file').createNewFile()
        }
    }
}
```